# How do you pronounce Thorin II Oakenshield?

Tags: the-hobbit, tolkiens-legendarium, pronunciation

How would you fully and properly speak Thorin's name, "**Thorin II Oakenshield**"?

Would you say "Thorin Oakenshield the Second"? Or "Thorin, the Second, Oakenshield"?

Same question goes for Dain II Ironfoot, Thorin III Stonehelm, and many others.

Comment: If he was a rapper it would be "Thorin2Oaken".

Comment: "Thorin OR Oakenshield"

Comment: I swear it's Thorin eye-eye Oakenshield

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The second way. Thorin Oakenshield is not the second "Thorin Oakenshield". Oakenshield is a nickname which applies only to him and not to his ancestor Thorin I. So the correct way to render it is "Thorin the Second, Oakenshield."

Or if you want a long-winded version that borrows from Game of Thrones, "Thorin, second of his name, called Oakenshield."

For a real world example, Alexander the Great was King Alexander III of Macedon, but he is not known as "Alexander the Great the Third". The "great" appellation does not apply to the previous two Alexanders because they didn't conquer the known world. If you want to specify both his number and nickname, it would be "Alexander the Third, the Great".

Comment: FWIW, the technical term for this is "[honorific](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honorific)", and is especially familiar from ancient and classical sources, e.g. "[Antiochus IV Epiphanes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiochus_Epiphanes)" (= "antiochus-the-fourth-epiphanes") in which "Antiochus" is the *name*, and "Epiphanes" (meaning "god-manifest") the *honorific*, or "[Artaxerxes I Makrocheir](http://www.livius.org/arl-arz/artaxerxes/artaxerxes_i_makrocheir.html)", where the "honorific" means "long hand". And so on.

Comment: @Davïd: Yes. Again FWIW, the numerical part is known as a "regnal number": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regnal_number

Comment: Awesome! That sounds right (even if it may sound weird, lol), "Dain the Second, Ironfoot!"

Comment: I suspect in fact that the answer is simply "You wouldn't ever use his 'full' name" -- he would be referred to either as "Thorin the Second" or as "Thorin Oakenshield" depending on circumstances. You'll note that Alexander is never in fact called "Alexander the Third, the Great" -- he's just Alexander the Great.

Comment: @Mike Not _necessarily_ so. Swedish kings, for example, still use this pattern today, although the ‘honorific’ in their case is an actual part of their name. Both regnal number and ‘honorific’ are frequently used together: the current king, _Carl XVI Gustaf_, is called _Carl Gustaf_ and _Carl den sextonde Gustaf_ with more or less equal frequency.